# method returns array of different objects

Tags: java

Im trying to write a method that return an array of different objects. i keep gertting different error for no apparent reason. please help me figure out whats wrong.

```
public static Object[] createArray( )  {//addReturnType createArray() {
  Computer c1 = new Computer("ASUS", "Intel", 8, 50, 2.4);
  Notebook n1 = new Notebook("Google", "Xeon", 20, 4, 4.5);
  Tablet t1 = new Tablet("APPLE", "AMD", 4, 25, 2.0, 11, 8, "IOS10");
  Computer c2 = new Computer("Dell", "Intel", 8, 23, 2.4);

  // define array

    Object[] arr = new Object[4];
    arr[1]=c1;
    arr[2]=n1;
    arr[3]=t1;
    arr[4]=c2;
     

      // return array
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero based.  A better way would be for a NoteBook or tablet to extend a computer, even better to create an Interface.

Comment: In other words, start at `arr[0]` and go to `arr[3]`. In the future, it's best to include your error in your question.

Comment: Wombat - that will probably be next week's class.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem waiting with bated breath.  Still in Welly?

Comment: Wombat - I don't recall making my location public.  Do you know me?